# Java : Type of Ref or new () decides which methods are visible

Tags: java

Say `Person` is base class.
`Doctor` class extends `Person`.

Now suppose `diagnose()` is method which belongs to `Doctor` class.

```
Person p = New Person();
Doctor q = (Doctor)p;
q.diagnose();
```

Why would this throw error?

`q` is object reference of kind `Doctor`.  All objects of class share same copy of methods, so `diagnose()` should be available to `q`.

There are no fields of methods which would be available to `p` would not be available in `Doctor`.
Why would java not allow this?

Comment: I know that it's just a typo, but you should fix the problems with the code. For example you said that `diagnose` is a method but it isn't written like one.

Comment: Your title is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 3):

> Why would this throw error?

Because you're casting an object of type `Person` to `Doctor`. The value of `p` is a reference to an instance of `Person`, not to an instance of `Doctor`, therefore the cast fails.

If you had:

```
Person p = new Doctor();
Doctor d = (Doctor) p;
d.diagnose();
```

*then* it would be fine.

This isn't a matter of what's *visible* - `d.diagnose()` is *visible* whenever `d` is a variable of type `Doctor`, as it is here. It's a matter of execution-time casting in the line *before* the `diagnose()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Because a Doctor is-a Person, by inheritance, but a Person isn't-a Doctor.